# Why is this scanf statement causing Segmentation Faults?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, scanf

I've been banging my head against this wall for an hour and I'm losing my mind... I have a piece of code (yes, it is homework) that throws a segmentation fault unless I comment out one of my scanf statements. I've tried to debug the problem using gdb, but I haven't really learned anything about that up until today.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


char * creditCard(char * ccNumber){
  char * lastFour;

  lastFour = (ccNumber + strlen(ccNumber) - 4);

  return lastFour;
}

void zipCode(int zip){
  printf("The zip code entered is: %d\n", zip);

}

int fuelGrade(int grade){

}

int main(void){
  char * ccNumber = NULL;
  int zip = 0;
  int gasGrade = 0;

  printf("Please Enter Credit Card Number: ");
  scanf("%s", ccNumber);

  printf("Please Enter Your Billing Zip Code: ");
  scanf("%d", &zip);

  printf("Select your Fuel Grade.\n Unleaded(1) Plus(2) Premium(3): ");
  scanf("%d", &gasGrade);


  ccNumber = creditCard(ccNumber);
  printf("****-****-****-%s\n", ccNumber);

  zipCode(zip);

  return 0;
}
```

When I compile and run as is I get the following:

```
Please Enter Credit Card Number: 123413515
Please Enter Your Billing Zip Code: Select your Fuel Grade.
Unleaded(1) Plus(2) Premium(3): 1
Segmentation fault
```

Entering the zip code is skipped and I get a segfault right after entering anything in fuel grade. However, if I comment out the *scanf("%d", &gasGrade);* line the code runs fine.

Originally I did not have the variables initialized and I had the code organized a little differently, but I can't seem to find the right solution to this problem. **What am I doing wrong here?**

Thanks for your help!

Comment: the ccnumber variable needs to point to an allocated memory area (that is longer than the max length of a credit card number)  suggest, where ccnumber is declared, append: = malloc(MAX_CC_NUM_LEN)  or something similar.  Remember to always check (!=NULL) the returned value from malloc() (and family of functions) to assure the operation was successful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because by doing `scanf("%s", ccNumber);` with `ccNumber = NULL` you are dereferencing a `NULL` pointer.

The `"%s"` specifier of `scanf()` expects a pointer to valid memory where it can write the scanned data, you are passing a `NULL` pointer, it does not check if the pointer is `NULL`, and hence it's dereferencing the `NULL` pointer.

You need valid memory, so you can use the stack in this case, like this

```
char  buffer[100];
char *ccNumber;
if (scanf("%99s", buffer) != 1)
    problemScanning_buffer_DoNotUse_buffer_In_TheFollowingCode();
ccNumber = creaditCard(buffer);
```

Note the `99` above, it prevents overflowing `buffer`, and you **MUST** always check the return value of `scanf()` to prevent Undefined Behavior.

Comment: Why does this not occur when the scanf("%d",&gasGrade); is not there? I appreciate the help, I'll see if it works in a minute

Comment: Because dereferencing a `NULL` pointer is undefined behavior, and the resulting behavior depends on other things in the program.

Answer (score 1):

You either have to allocate memory for ccNumber using `malloc` or define it as an array `char ccNumber[17]` (16 digits + \0 character). Right now it is a pointer to a single char that you initialize to `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

You do not allocate memory for cc Number (ccNumber is NULL)

When reading a number you have to clear the line break character, but to read another value with scanf, automatically read the '\ n' that is in the input buffer (stdin).

```
printf("Please Enter Your Billing Zip Code: ");
scanf("%d", &zip);
```

Change:

```
scanf("%d", &zip);
```

To:

```
scanf("%d%*c", &zip);
```

Comment: "When reading a number you have to clear the line break character"... That's funny, because [my manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fscanf.html) says otherwise: "Input white-space characters (as specified by isspace()) shall be skipped, unless the conversion specification includes a [, c, C, or n conversion specifier."

Comment: There is space, is a line break. Scanf not read line break ('\n'). Your manual is totally wrong.

Comment: Opengroup is wrong? What about [the C standard](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html#7.21.6.2p8)?

Comment: Is `'\n'` included in the set for which [`isspace`](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html#7.4.1.10) returns true? See the C standard... It's more credible than your K&R book. Did I get over 5k rep answering 337 answers, 298 of which had the `c` tag in them for lying to people? My sources are credible.

Comment: It was you who said '\ n' is ignored because of isspace, not me !!!! No matter how many k answers / votes you have, this has nothing to do with programming knowledge, or at least know the language in which program.